# Jquery in page tabs using iframe

Tags: jquery, tabs, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

For some reason the jquery I have on my tab will not work, it works fine on the actual link that I am loading in.

Here is JS that is being used in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/royal-slider-2.0.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {  
        $.internshipSlider = new RoyalSlider("#internshipPrograms", {
            directionNavEnabled:true,
            directionNavAutoHide:false,
            controlNavEnabled:false,
            welcomeScreenEnabled:false
        });

        $.internshipSlider.settings.beforeSlideChange = function() {
            // change the "active" state for the slide in the nav
            $("#nav"+this.lastSlideId).removeClass("active");
            $("#nav"+this.currentSlideId).addClass("active");
        }

        $.internshipSlider.settings.afterSlideChange = function() {
            //currently not doing anything after slide change
        }





    function sliderChange(slideIndex) {
        // public function for changing the slides via a link
        $.internshipSlider.goTo(slideIndex);
    }



    /* --- EXPANDED TEXT --- */
    var hiddenText = true;
    function toggleExpandedText () {
        if (hiddenText) {
            $("#text-box-expanded").show("blind");
            $("#moreTextBtn").text("Hide...");
            hiddenText = false;
        } else {
            $("#text-box-expanded").hide("blind");
            $("#moreTextBtn").text("More...");
            hiddenText = true;
        }
    }




</script>
```

Am I missing a step in loading this into to page to make it work? Problem with the DOM? Sorry I am new with this and under some pressure to get this done quickly. Id appreciate any help on this...

thanks!

Comment: I don't see a script element calling jQuery itself. Did you neglect to put that in the post? Also, best to wrap your code in a [`ready()` call](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your javascript console in Chrome debugger tools for errors, and make sure jquery is actually being referenced because it is not in the code you posted.